# v-model default value when it comes from Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

All inputs in the form are bind via v-model to the data in the Vue component like this

```
<validation-provider name="first_name" rules="required" v-slot="{ failed, errors }" :debounce="500">
<input  type="text" 
        id="first_name" 
        name="first_name" 
        placeholder="First name"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{'is-invalid' : failed}"
        :disabled="loading"
        value="{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}"
        tabindex="1"
        v-model.trim="user.first_name"
>
<div class="invalid-feedback" v-show="failed">
         @{{ errors[0] }}
</div>
```

v-model doesn't show a default value if there is one value="{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}" so I'm trying to solve this issue like this

```
data() {
        return {
            user: {
                first_name: document.querySelector("input[name=first_name]").value,
            },

            loading: false
        };
    },
```

But I'm very sure this is not the best way to do this. I've tried looking for an answer, but they are kinda the same. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: You're using a `value` prop, as well as `v-model`, this is conflicting. `v-model` is nothing but a combination of two things, a `value` prop, and an `input` event listener. Read up more on the [basic usage of `v-model` here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage). One of the first tips also mentions that when `v-model` is used, the `value` prop will be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, I did read this but maybe I don't understand it. So should I just use the value and try to bind the input to the data property another way, not with v-model?

Comment: use v-model for binding. you need not to use value attribute.

Comment: I do. This is a settings form so I already have saved values in the database that are coming from laravel and I want to show those if there are any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to find a way pass that user information to (vue)js. your solution isnt wrong but in vue.js we work with data or state so my solution is create custom component for this problem like:

```js
// blade
<UserForm :data='@json(auth()->user())' />

// component data
data() {
    return {
        user: this.data,
        loading: false
        // and what ever you need
    };
},
```

of course there is a another way and you put user data in window DOM object throw head tag of your blade file. here:

```html
    @auth
        <script>
            window.user = @json(auth()->user())
        </script>
    @endauth
```

then you can access it in you components:

```js
data() {
    return {
        user: {
            first_name: window.user.first_name
        },
        loading: false
    };
},
```